# Sibling order: "my sister NEXT TO ME

Tags: phrase-request

Let's say you are the *eldest* in a family of 5. You, sister and brother. Your sister has a child now, and you are describing how you are related to your nephew to one of your guests. You say:

> This is my nephew, carl. The son of my sister **next to me.**

Is this the correct phrase to explain what I am trying to say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If she’s your only sister it’s “my sister” (or “my younger sister” if she’s younger than you; “my older sister” if she’s older than you). If you have two sisters it’s either “my older sister” or “my younger sister”. If you have three sisters it could be either of those (EDIT: “oldest” or “youngest” are more appropriate for comparing more than two) or “my middle sister.” If you have more than three sisters maybe you could say “my second-oldest sister” or “my fifth-youngest sister” etc.

Answer (score 3):

I think **nearest** gets closest to the meaning you want - saying **next to me** is only used for physical proximity.

> "My sister **next to me**" is the sister who is standing or sitting right beside me (physical proximity).
>
> "My **nearest** sister" is the sister who is immediately older or younger, though depending on context it could also be the sister who is the least far away at the moment (either age or physical proximity).
>
> "My **sister who is closest in age [to me]**" is somewhat long-winded, but is really the only unambiguous way to convey the meaning you want (age proximity).

also:

> "My **closest** sister" usually means the sister you get along with the best or who you talk with most frequently (emotional proximity).

Answer (score 2):

If she's one down from you, it could be "my sister, the next oldest", leaving "of our sibling group" implicit because it sounds dumb. If she's one up for you, it could be "my sister, the next youngest", similarly. I wouldn't be confident people will understand what you mean first time (some will, some won't - there may be dialect impact), but it won't sound *weird*, just unfamiliar.